# Using ts() with multiple observation per date

Tags: r

```
Date           u   v  w      Feeder
01/01/2017      7  7  3        a
01/01/2017      2  49 32       e
01/01/2017      79 87 23       i

01/02/2017      0  0  0        a
01/02/2017      0  0  0        e
01/02/2017     789 78 33       i

...              ...          ...

01/05/2018       0   0  0      a
01/05/2018      789 78 33      e
01/05/2018       25 78 22      i
```

Above is the data table format I am using.
My ultimate goal is to do time series analysis using `tslm()`.

df is myDataFrame.

```
 TS <- ts(df1[,2:length(df)],frequency = 12, start = c(2017,1), end =c(2018,12)
```

My Problem:

With such a code I will have only one row per month and my "Feeder" column will be filled with NA's.
Moreover, it will exhibit 24 months whereas I only have 17 months.

EDIT:
I assume to have the same hour for every row.

Comment: not sure if this helps but for working with TS the `zoo` package offers alot of functionality.

Comment: The frequency argument is something you will need to decide prior to your time series based on knowledge about the cycles in your data. Are your three daily measurements from set times (12a, 8a, 4p), if so you might have two cycles: the yearly one and a daily one. Then you'll want to look at `forecast::msts()`.

Comment: @Nate I use only one single hour per row as highlighted in my EDITs.